# The means are statistically equal

Tags: r, anova

What does it mean "The means are statistically equals?" I ask this question because I'm studing ANOVA (`anova()` function in R) and I know that this test checks if the means of N groups are statistically equals.

My doubt concerns what "statistically equals" means because if I have two series like:

```
A <- c(2,4,12,14)
```

the mean is **8**

But if I do

```
B <- c(-20,-10, 10, 52)
```

the mean is always **8** but the number are totally differents.

So the question is: does it check if the means are similar and stop OR check if the means are similar AND also check if the number that "generate" this mean are similar?

Thank you

Comment: The only usages of "statistically equal" I am aware of originate in non-statistical (and usually informal) contexts.  Do you have a specific quotation in mind, a source you can reference?

Comment: @whuber my doubt concerns if a test checks the "means" it means that the means need to be equals (less or more) OR it checks the means and the number that generate that means?

Comment: It seems to me you should specify whether you mean the "means" as in "empirical means" or in "distributional means"...

Comment: @Xi'an I mean the "average" of each group

Comment: Actually, Dail, your question does *not* use "mean" in the sense of an average a group of data.  If it did, it would be sublimely Zen-like, because it would be asking "when is 8 (a number equal to the mean of (2,4,12,14)) not equal to 8 (a number equal to the mean of (-20,-10,10,52))?" The correct and incontrovertible answer would be "never: 8 always equals 8."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already accepted one answer, and it's a fine answer. But to directly answer your question:

> So the question is: does it check if the means are similar and stop OR
>   check if the means are similar AND also check if the number that
>   "generate" this mean are similar?

ANOVA checks only the first.

Further "statistically equal" is, as @whuber points out, not good statistical usage; in statistical terms, this would be the equivalent of accepting the null hypothesis. However, we never accept the null, we simply fail to reject it.  It is similar to criminal trials (at least, in the USA) where the defendant is found "guilty" or "not guilty" - never "innocent". The prosecution must prove guilt beyond a certain standard (reasonable doubt); the defense need do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The analysis of variance you are referring to considers a **single variable** which is observed in **several groups**.
The null hypothesis states that the mean of that variable is equal in each group:

$H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 = \ldots = \mu_g$.

But there are a number of assumptions that underly the test. One of them requires **homoscedasticity**. In other words, the (true) variance of the variable is the same in each subpopulation. Normality is also assumed. With those assumptions, if differences do exist between the groups, then they differ in terms of localisations only.

Comment: For the sake of understanding the connection between this reply and the question, please note that in the question "mean" refers to the average of a set of data whereas in this reply "mean" refers to a parameter of a hypothetical distribution.

Comment: @Whuber: You are right indeed. But I guess there is some confusion in the question which seems to be about ANOVA...

Comment: @ocram it is an ANOVA question, I mean the "average" of each groups. It will check the "average" if are equal (less or more) OR it will also check the values that "generate" that average ?

Comment: @chl: What was your edit???

Comment: He corrected a misspelling.  You should be able to see the editing record simply by clicking on the duration indicator following "edited" beneath the text of your reply.

Comment: @Whuber: oh, I had never noticed! Thx :-)